# Should Angular2 module class contain any functionality?

Tags: angular

We import services, components, directives and pipes into a module. Should we define methods or variables in a module class like this?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...]
})
export class FooModule { 
    name: string;
    sayHi(): void { }
}
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of any case where you would need to. I think any functionality you needed in a module could be handled in a service.

Comment: @LLai Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is basically a collection of components. And each component in a module has its own functionality handled in its class. In angular 2, its a syntactical practice to export components to be imported in a module and export modules to be imported by other modules. However since all components have their logic coded in their respective classes their is no need to have logic written in the module class.